# How to load Feature Layer over Raster Layer in Android ESRI ArcGIS 10.2.9?

Tags: android, gis, arcgis, esri-maps

I am trying to load a map from a url with different layers using arcgis sdk.

I'm using **ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer** to load the multi-layer map . Everything works fine except Feature Layer is not loading over Raster layer.

There are 8 layers inside map in which 7 of them are Feature Layers and 1 is Raster layer . If i hide all the Feature Layers then the Raster Layer becomes visible . If any of feature layer made visible then Raster layer becomes invisible .

My actual problem is that I need to show Feature layers above the Raster layer . I am entirely new to GIS , any help .

Following is the sdk which i'm using 
**com.esri.arcgis.android:arcgis-android:10.2.9**

Here is how i generate MAP and add to map view

```
 arcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer(MAP_URL);
 mMapView.addLayer(arcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer);
```

and here is the code used to show and hide Layers

```
 this.arcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer.getLayers()[position].setVisible(visible);
 this.arcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer.refresh();
```

Comment: Please show us some code that adds feature layers to the map. Also, make sure you add the raster layer first and then the feature layers, since the last layer added displays on top. You can use `MapView.addLayer(Layer, int)` ( https://developers.arcgis.com/android/10-2/api-reference/reference/com/esri/android/map/MapView.html#addLayer(com.esri.android.map.Layer, int) ) if you need to add layers out of order (0 is the first layer drawn, i.e. below all other layers).

Comment: @GaryS. I am not adding any layers manually instead the MAP_URL itself  generates it  . The single MAP_URL itself contains multiple layers both FEATURE layer and RASTER layer which i'm loading in to MAP view using  ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer and uses menu  to show and hide the layers using position

Comment: Oh, okay. And does the map service behave properly in a web browser or in the ArcGIS API for JavaScript samples? I'm asking because I want to know if the problem is with Android or with the service.

Comment: Yes its working perfectly in web browser where Android having Issue

Comment: Your service isn't on the public internet, is it? If it is, can you please share the URL?

Comment: Here's a service that looks like your situation (one raster layer with multiple feature layers on top): http://pricecontourmap.spp.org/arcgis/rest/services/MarketMaps/RTBM_LMP_MOSAIC/MapServer . This service works great for me in ArcGIS Runtime 10.2.9 for Android. All layers are fine. Try this service in your app. Also, you could try capturing network traffic to see what requests are being made (see http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/configureforandroid ). And you could create a ticket with Esri Support.

Comment: No Gary , my service isn't on the public internet . Let me check with the service you commented and i will get back to you soon . Thank you